# User authentication on different domains

Tags: php, authentication

I have a PHP `API` on `example.com` that authenticates users based on `Sessions`.

I am working on a mobile app for that, but whenever the user does a POST Ajax request to the `API`, it responds with `set-cookie` headers.

Obviously cookies cannot be sent on the mobile application because they're coming from a different domain.

How can I make the authentication process work on mobile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rule #1 of RESTful APIs: HTTP is stateless - keep it that way.

If you want a neat fix to your dilemma, consider implementing something to get the session ID out of a GET, POST parameter or out of a header (I usually do it using the Authorization header, personally). This then allows you to not have to rely on cookies unless you have to.

A hackish fix to your problem would be to set the cookie domain to *.example.com, which would map every domain, or to force the cookie to be added using jQuery (if you use it)'s `beforeSend` callback (which allows you to modify the headers of the request). Short of modifying your API's log-in method, these are your only options.

Comment: Can you please explain more regarding the first method?
You mean I send the PHPSESSID and I save it in the localStorage? then whenever I want to check if the user is logged in or not, I send it back from the localStorage to the server?

Comment: @JadJoubran: pretty much. You allow your user to send his session ID via cookie **and** another field. This allows you to localStorage the cookie whenever needed.

Comment: okay great. Last question: on the server side, I'll not be able to read his session data.. or I can create the session from that field?

Comment: @JadJoubran: Little known fact: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php